# mmu in arm: how to map kernel code (bare metal)

Tags: arm64, bare-metal, mmu

In the link script, the starting address is 0xffffffff00000000. I can then load my own bare metal kernel (for aarch64) in an arbitrary (physical) address and use relative addressing. So when I turn on MMU, how do I know memory won't be written at where kernel is loaded? I mean, if I loaded kernel at 0x01000000, and map physical memory from 0xffffffff00000000 to 0xffffffffffffffff, it seems to me I will still be running into problems if I combine relative with absolute addressing. And it seems like the only solution is to ensure the kernel is loaded always at the same physical address, and then to map that to 0xffffffff00000000... But somehow this beats the purpose of an MMU. Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: `how do I know memory won't be written at where kernel is loaded?` - because you're the operating system and you don't _let_ anyone write there?

Comment: After a good night of thinking about this, I guess I need to have some bootloader logic that will always be loaded on the same physical address.

Comment: If you're talking about absolute addresses that the linker wrote out - then yes, you'll need to apply the slide to all of those at boot, before running code that may depend on such hardcoded addresses.

Comment: Ah, I think I actually realized something. On aarch64, using adr x0, some_label I get it's physical address in x0... And for ldr x0, some_label, I get relative to start address from linker. I mean I just tested it out, and it does work, my problem here was thinking that adr also returned relative to start address.

Comment: "I guess I need to have some bootloader logic that will always be loaded on the same physical address"  The processor boots at a known hardcoded address and your bare metal code must be in tune with that, be it position independent or not, your choice.  But yes of course a bootloader at the same physical address is exactly how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the realization that ADR instruction on Aarch64 returns physical address helped me achieve what I wanted. I hope I am right in my thinking, though:

```
ADR x0, label  # here we get physical address of label to x0
LDR x0, =label # here we get start address from linker + label address to x0
```

So I don't really need to know the physical address (at which the kernel was loaded) at compile time to set a boundary around kernel to set MMU up properly.